# Ruby to python one-liner conversion

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django

I have a little one-liner in my Rails app that returns a range of copyright dates with an optional parameter, e.g.:

```
def copyright_dates(start_year = Date.today().year)
    [start_year, Date.today().year].sort.uniq.join(" - ")
end
```

I'm moving the app over to Django, and while I love it, I miss a bit of the conciseness. The same method in Python looks like:

```
def copyright_dates(start_year = datetime.datetime.today().year):
    years = list(set([start_year, datetime.datetime.today().year]))
    years.sort()
    return " - ".join(map(str, years))
```

It's been years since I've touched Python, so I'm betting there's an easier way to do it. Any ideas?

**EDIT**: I know lists and sets are a bit of overkill, but I want the following output assuming the code is run in 2009:

```
copyright_dates()     # '2009'
copyright_dates(2007) # '2007 - 2009'
copyright_dates(2012) # '2009 - 2012'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

def copyright_dates(start_year = datetime.now().year):
    return " - ".join(str(y) for y in sorted(set([start_year, datetime.now().year])))
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I was able to get it down to " - ".join(map(str, sorted(set([start_year, datetime.now().year])))) if I left out the list comprehension.

Answer (score 5):

Watch out for the default parameter which is evaluated once.  So if your web application runs over 12/31/09 without a restart, you won't get the expected output.

Try:

```
def copy(start=None):
    start, curr = start if start else datetime.today().year, datetime.today().year
    return str(start) if start == curr else '%d - %d' % tuple(sorted([start, curr]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Lists and sets seem to be overkill to me.

How about this:

```
def copyright_dates(start=datetime.datetime.today().year):
    now = datetime.datetime.today().year
    return (start==now and str(now) or "%d - %d" % (min(start, now), max(start, now)))
```

Comment: Also nice, only thing missing is the sort, if for some reason I decided to pass in a future date. That's the only reason I use the lists and sets. I'll update the question with the expected output.

Comment: No need for sort when you're dealing with only two items. The order issue is fixed now, I believe.